# R / leaflet - drawing numerous polygons

Tags: r, leaflet, projection

I am trying to draw numerous polygons with the leaflet package but I can't understand what's going wrong.

The shapefile I use can be found here: https://www.data.gouv.fr/en/datasets/fond-de-carte-des-codes-postaux/

```
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
df <- readOGR("C:/Users/me/codes_postaux","codes_postaux_region")
plot(df)
```

[image: output shapefile]

The shapefile seems ok to me and the code I use is rather simple. However I only get the map as an output and no Polygons. I've been struggling with this issue for quite a long time, I would really appreciate if someone could help me here.

```
map <- leaflet(df) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")%>%
  fitBounds(10,38,10,55) %>% 
  addPolygons(fillOpacity = 0.8, color = "Blue", weight = 1)

map
```

[image: leaflet]

Comment: Does it work with this data: `df <- raster::getData("GADM", country = "FRA", level = 4)` ? It does for me, just wondering whether it is your data or some package related issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `df@proj4string` and the output of `plot(df); axis(1); axis(2)`. Your shapefile uses a specific CRS. You need to transform your `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` with a common `CRSobj` (I got the CRS code from here: [Leaflet for R: Raster Images](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/raster.html)).

```
library(sp)

pj <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
df2 <- spTransform(df, pj)

map2 <- leaflet(df2) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")%>%
  fitBounds(10,38,10,55) %>% 
  addPolygons(fillOpacity = 0.8, color = "Blue", weight = 1)
map2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works well. Can you please specify how you found the projection argument in CRS() ?

Comment: @PierreDudek; I knew it is the most common one, so I used it (I didn't search it when I answered). But now I found CRS in the leaflet description for R and I rewrote the CRS into it (their difference is a just expression) (see: [Leaflet for R: Raster Images](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/raster.html))